# How to convert Float to Varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing this

```
declare @num float = 7708369000

select  @num as [float], 
    convert(varchar, @num) as [varchar]
```

it gives me this

```
float                  varchar
---------------------- ------------------------------
7708369000             7.70837e+009
```

But I want this

```
float                  varchar
---------------------- ------------------------------
7708369000             7708369000
```

Please help.

Comment: Simple google search "Formatting a float in varchar but NOT in scientific notation" **Result**: http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/80603-formatting-float-varchar-but-not-scientific-notation

Answer (score 27, accepted):

convert it to decimal first,

```
CAST(CAST(@num AS DECIMAL(20)) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f0e3/8)

Comment: what about fractional part?

Comment: this does not appear to be correct as it truncates the fractional part, thus only works correct for numbers which have 0 in the fractional portion

Comment: Change DECIMAL(20) to DECIMAL(20, S) where S is the desired number of decimal places.  S (scale) must be less than or equal to P (precision) for datatype DECIMAL(P, S).

Answer (score 8):

Try using the Str function rather than using convert

```
DECLARE @num float = 7708369000;    
SELECT Str(@num);
```

Comment: Sorry for the earlier one, wrote 25 and 0 parameters by mistake. The above edited solution should work fine and should not introduce any white spaces.

Comment: this does not appear to be correct as it truncates the fractional part, thus only works correct for numbers which have 0 in the fractional portion

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following variations (values represent Max Value of BigInt and other Max type values) that meet your needs below.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/745c8f/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
   FloatDefault float,  --Default is 24 bits giving 7 digit precision and 4 bytes storage
   Float24 float(24),   --Max for 4 bytes storage, 24 bits giving 7 digit precision and 4 bytes storage
   Float53 float(53)    --Max for 8 bytes storage, 53 bits giving 15 digit precision and 8 bytes storage
);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(-9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808, -9223372036854775808); --Max Negative Value of a Big Int
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807, 9223372036854775807);  --Max Positive Value of a Big Int
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(-2147483648, -2147483648, -2147483648); --Max Negative Value of a Big Int
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(2147483647, 2147483647, 2147483647);  --Max Positive Value of a Big Int
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(123456789012345678901234567890, 123456789012345678901234567890, 123456789012345678901234567890);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(123456789012345678901234567890.12345678, 123456789012345678901234567890.12345678, 123456789012345678901234567890.12345678);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1234567890, 1234567890, 1234567890);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1234567890.0123456789, 1234567890.0123456789, 1234567890.0123456789);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(22.0/7.0, 22.0/7.0, 22.0/7.0); -- Value of Pi
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(2000.0, 2000.0, 2000.0);

SELECT 
   FloatDefault,
   Float24,
   Float53,   
   CAST(CAST(Float53  AS NUMERIC(38)) AS VARCHAR(100)), -- 38 is the max precision 
   CAST(CAST(Float53  AS NUMERIC(38,5)) AS VARCHAR(100)), 
   STR(Float53),
   STR(Float53, 38),
   STR(Float53, 38,5),
   LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Float53, 38,5))),
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, Float53),
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Float53),
   CONVERT(NUMERIC(38,5), Float53)
FROM Table1
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following function:

*STR(number, length, decimal)*

- *number* is the numeric value to convert to a string
- *length* is the length of the result string. Default value is 10
- *decimal*    is the number of decimals places to round off. Default value is 0

Ref: [STR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)