# Why do I have to cast a float to a decimal and then a decimal into a varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #TestFloat (id int, floattest float)
insert into #TestFloat values (1,65478)
insert into #TestFloat values (1,65478888)
insert into #TestFloat values (1,42)
```

How would I cast the float values to a varchar? I have tried this:

```
select top 1 cast(floattest as varchar(15)) from #TestFloat
```

which produces this:

```
6.54789e+007
```

and this:

```
select top 1 id,Str(floattest, 15, 0) from #TestFloat

'          65478'
```

I have put quotes in the above to demonstrate that it is casted into a char.

This works (taken from this question: [How to convert Float to Varchar in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760956/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql)):

```
select CAST(CAST(floattest AS DECIMAL(20)) AS VARCHAR(20)) from #TestFloat
```

Why do I have to cast into a decimal first?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT FORMAT(floattest,'R') FROM #TestFloat
```

(Or `'G'` or `'N'` depending on your use) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

or

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(floattest,8,0)) FROM #TestFloat
```

(Pick your precision and scale to suit but watch out for rounding)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189527.aspx

You also ask "why"? You should probably have a read of the MSDN pages on SQL Server types starting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187752.aspx and this answer [Difference between numeric, float and decimal in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use convert function in sql server

```
select top 1 CONVERT (NVARCHAR(15),floattest) from #TestFloat
```

Comment: Why is a convert to a varchar/nvarchar different to a cast to a varchar/nvarchar?

Comment: Sorry mean select top 1 CONVERT (VARCHAR(15),floattest) from #TestFloat

Answer (score 0):

First cast to decimal and then to varchar.

**Query**

```
SELECT CAST
       (
           CAST(floattest AS DECIMAL(25,0)) 
           AS VARCHAR(MAX)
       ) 
FROM #TestFloat;
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa4a6/2)